# Enabling namespaces in Babel breaks Flow transpilation in React Native project

Tags: typescript, react-native, babeljs, flowtype

I have a React Native project using TypeScript, which includes React Native packages in `node_modules` that include Flow syntax.

I'm having trouble getting *both* TypeScript and Flow to transpile correctly.

This works (`babel.config.js`) for Flow syntax, but prevents TypeScript code like `export namespace MyNamespace`:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', {legacy: true}],
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', {loose: true}],
  ],
};
```

This (after adding Babel plugin to enable TypeScript namespaces) breaks on, for example, `import type {...} from '...'`:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', {legacy: true}],
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', {loose: true}],
    ['@babel/plugin-transform-typescript', {allowNamespaces: true}],
  ],
};
```

In other words, adding the `@babel/plugin-transform-typescript` plugin breaks Flow transpilation.

I've tried different settings in `tsconfig.json`, but I have then since learned that the TypeScript settings in there are effectively ignored by Babel.

**Edit:** I seem to have it working for the Metro bundler by modifying my `metro.config.js` file like so to use TypeScript for the transpiling instead of relying on the built-in TypeScript support in Babel 7:

```
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: true,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-typescript-transformer") // This is key to using TypeScript instead of Babel for transpiling TS(X) files
  },
};
```

Note that `react-native-typescript-transformer` needs to be installed using NPM or Yarn: `yarn add react-native-typescript-transformer --dev`.

Now I just need to get it to work properly for local Jest tests... :)

Comment: Hi, thank you for posting the update. I wondering if you got the Jest part working and also if you did notice any overhead changing the default `babelTransformerPath `. Tkx.